# Why does google use /oauth2/auth and Auth0 spec uses /oauth2/authorize

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, oauth, auth0

I'm trying to use the auth0-react package, which redirects the user to the provided domain + /authorize

```
 <Auth0Provider
    domain="mydomain/oauth2"
    // redirects to mydomain/oauth2/authorize?...
    clientId="myClientId"
    redirectUri={"http://localhost:1557/send-params"}
  />
...
```

The problem is, the domain I'm trying to request uses the path `/auth` as opposed to `/authorize`, as stated in the Auth0 OAuth 2.0 spec. I'm wondering why the spec and the SDK direct to `/authorize`, and some providers, like Google, use `/auth`.

Also, if anyone has experience with the `auth0-react` package, is there a way to change the endpoint that is called from `/authorize` to `/auth`?

Answer (score 1):

The correct library behaviour should be to look up endpoints using OpenID Connect Discovery, since there is nothing in standards to say what the endpoint relative URLs are.

Hopefully there is an Auth0 option to do this - I will take a look at the Auth0 repo later. Generally though I avoid vendor specific libraries for this type of reason.

[OIDC Client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) is an example library that works with any standards based provider. But then SPAs are moving to more of a back end for front end pattern anyway - hence this library being archived.

**POSTSCRIPT**

I have a look and it seems that the above library depends on the [auth0-spa-js library and its Auth0Client class](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/blob/master/src/Auth0Client.ts#L247) which hard codes the path. You may be able to subclass this client to solve your problem.